# Height constraint animation of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I have UIView named DetailView with following constraints:

```
DetailView.top = top
DetailView.trailing = Safe Area.trailing
DetailView.leading = Safe Area.leading
height = 295
```

All made in StoryBoard. [DetailView is this gray rectangle on an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZNsO.png)

I would like to change height of this UIView after tapping a button, so I have IBAction to achieve this

```
@IBAction func detailViewTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if detailViewHeightConstraint.constant < 500 {
            detailViewHeightConstraint.constant = 523
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.detailView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
            arrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: "up-arrow")
        } else {
            detailViewHeightConstraint.constant = 295
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.detailView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
            arrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: "down-arrow")
        }
    }
```

Changing size works perfect, but animation not. I would like to achieve effect of expanding to the bottom, but animation start something in between of screen and is expanding to the bottom and to the top. [Start of animation can be seen on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSpn3.png) How can I achieve desirable effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animate main view

```
 @IBAction func detailViewTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if detailViewHeightConstraint.constant < 500 {
        detailViewHeightConstraint.constant = 523
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        arrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: "up-arrow")
    } else {
        detailViewHeightConstraint.constant = 295
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        arrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: "down-arrow")
    }
}
```